Query works fine in the self-managed Clickhouse but doesn`t work in the Cloud
Exactly the same query works fine in the self-managed Clickhouse but doesn`t work in the Cloud.
I have no idea why...
Please help
Query:
SELECT arrayMap(hit -> arrayMap(product -> product.id,hit.product),hits ) AS `hits.product.id`
FROM table

Expected type as a result: Array(Array(String))
Source column "hits" datatype:
hits(Array(
        Tuple(hitId String, 
              product Array(Tuple(id String,
                                  isImpression String,
                                  impressionList String,
                                  productBrand String
                                  )
                            )
            )       
        )
)

Error:
SQL Error [47] [07000]: Code: 47. DB::Exception: Missing columns: 'hit.product' 'product.id' while processing query: 'SELECT arrayMap(hit -> arrayMap(product -> product.id, hit.product), hits) AS `hits.product.id` FROM marketing_raw_data.owoxbi_sessions_', required columns: 'product.id' 'hits' 'hit.product', maybe you meant: 'hits'. (UNKNOWN_IDENTIFIER) (version 24.6.3.95 (official build))


That's probably the new analyzer. You should open a support ticket and they'll take care of it for you.

Add settings allow_experimental_analyzer = 1; to the end of your query, and it will work. Repro here - https://pastila.nl/?03abee9a/f06a673be566b28fb595dc3a4cfe8686#1H+pZgsQLUIfOcIUBPoNUg==
